# What do pilots do on a windshear alert after V1?

Tags: takeoff, windshear

What is a pilot taught to do, when a windshear is detected and the planes speed is above V1 and before Vr? I can't think of what is safer.

- Rejecting, with the risk of overshooting the runway.
- Taking off, with the risk of the windshear stalling the plane and dropping it on the ground. If the height of the aircraft was low it probably would just overshoot the runway. If the aircraft already gained some altitude, it could crash.

As well, are there any differences in procedures if the alert occured

- After V1 but before Vr
- After Vr

Comment: After Vr you would have already taken off. No chance of rejecting at that moment.

Comment: What do you think V1 means?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

V1 is the calculated decision point at which takeoff *must* continue. Unless the aircraft is suffering a catastrophic failure, the pilot should not abort takeoff after V1.

The danger when taking off during windshear is the sudden lost of airspeed may result in the airplane settling back on the ground after it has become airborne. The technique, therefore, is aimed at gaining ground clearance in the shortest amount of time possible. In general, this involves:

- Apply max thrust
- Delay rotation
- Once rotation is initiated, quickly pitch up to gain altitude

Below is an extract from the Boeing 777 FCOM about taking off when windshear is suspected (my emphasis):

> - Takeoff with **less than full rated thrust is not recommended** (...)
> - Use the longest suitable runway (...)
> - Consider **increasing Vr speed** to the performance limited gross weight rotation speed. (...) If windshear is encountered at or beyond
>     the actual gross weight Vr, do not attempt to accelerate to the
>     increased Vr, but **rotate without hesitation**.
> - (...) Minimize reductions from the initial climb pitch attitude until terrain and obstruction clearance is assured, unless stick
>     shaker activates.
> - (...) **Stick shaker must be respected** at all times.

Answer (score 10):

What pilots are ***taught*** is that V1 is the go/no-go decision point.  So after V1 they will continue with the take off, but the PIC is the final authority as to the operation of the flight and may take an action that he or she determines is best depending on the specific scenario.

Regarding Vr: pilots are trained to do thorough pre-flight planning and become familiar with the flight plan and weather conditions at the point of departure, route of flight, and destination at the calculated time of arrival.  The pilots should know if there are windy weather conditions, an approaching front, or storm so that they can delay or cancel the flight or increase the Vr speed for takeoff from the standard Vr speed and have some extra buffer.  That way if there is windshear they have a higher safety margin between their climb speed and stall speed.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to keep full throttle, and try to hold the plane in ground effect until reaching a fairly high speed. Then, start increasing altitude slowly and carefully...

Comment: But the question isn't what you would do; the question is what pilots are taught to do.

Comment: The question is (poorly) states both ways.  Look at the title.

Comment: If windshear occurs when the plane is slowly gaining altitude, the plane may drop back onto the runway hard, leading to structural damage and potentially loss of control.

Comment: You're going to fly right into the hill/building at the end of the runway.

Answer (score 1):

Windshear alert will not occur while on the ground on Airbuses; you will only get the alert once airborne, after Vr. I suspect most manufacturers have implemented a similar feature, perhaps, in order to prevent pilots from rejecting after V1.

What to do is usually a precise and exact procedure. While it does vary from type to type the main items are in common:

- Use full available power
- pitch up for a max rate of climb
- maintain a/c configuration (no gear or flaps retract)

Answer (score 1):

In case of an engine failure, the total available thrust to the aircraft be reduced by 50% and it will lose at least 80% of the available climb thrust.  Suffer wind shear in these conditions, the airplane may not be able to sustain a positive rate of climb on one engine, making it very dangerous at low levels.  If low level wind shear conditions are anticipated at or in the vicinity of the airport, the pilot should consider this as part of the pre-takeoff briefing or postpone flight operations until conditions subside.  Have a plan based upon the procedures listed in the AFM and stick with it.  If an LLWAS alert is heard or if wind shear is encountered past V1, in general you’re past the point of no return and the airplane is going flying - unless you’re absolutely certain you can still stop it with the remaining runway available at your current takeoff weight, but that’s up to the captain to make that call.  Most jets have a considerably higher OEI performance margin than do light or medium twins and would take a pretty strong wind shear in order to threaten climbout on OEI.  Some things a pilot might do in those circumstances.

- Advance both thrust levers to maximum.
- Delay rotation or remain in ground effect until V2 has been attained.  Accept additional touchdown on runway of airplane cannot sustain a climb until V2 is reached.
- Select a Vr with an appropriate wind shear margin added on.
- If sustained positive rate of climb is possible and attained, retract the gear to remove parasite drag.

Comment: retracting the gear is exactelly the wrong move: think about it, if you are climbing steadly, then why get greedy and retract the gear? if you are not in a sustained climb, then why retract the gear at all? both cases it’s a wrong move, guaranteed to fail your checkride

Comment: Because you will get rid of the parasite drag faster and accelerate quicker to V2, allow for a greater rate of climb once you are maintaining V2 or flying at Vyse.  And unless you have a manufacturer recommended OEI procedure saying otherwise, you will retract the landing gear once a positive rate is attained. Any examiner who would fail you for that is a moron who has no clue about flying multi engine aircraft.

Comment: seriously: retracting gear(or flaps)  in windshear is a ‘fail-able offence’ :-)  where I live in EASA-land .I understand it seems counterintuitive,  I just always supposed  that the action of ‘retracting’ the gear will create more drag initially with doors opening etc. I’ll look for the actual regs on this one tomorrow morning

Comment: No, the name of the game here is to get clear of the runway and obstacles as quickly as possible.  Once you hit V1 1) you’re going flying at that point, so when Vr comes you will establish a pitch up appropriate to the aircraft type and depart.  If wind shear is encountered at that point a pilot will ensure a positive and sustained rate of climb is indicated, then retract the gear.  The last thing you need at that point is the gear hanging out of the airplane and impeding climb performance.  You don’t need to divert extra climb thrust to fighting through the parasite drag of the gear.

Comment: @Radu094 Acceptable Means of Compliance and Guidance Material to Part-FCL, AMC1 FCL.930.MCCI, Part 3 point (b)(7), looks relevant, though not authoritative for what you're after.

Comment: These guys do a great example of departure procedures in pre and post V1 wind shear in an A320 simulator.  Note the FO retracts the landing gear only after a positive rate of climb in obtained and keeps the gear retracted throughout the emergency.   https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nCy1tAfLbDg

Comment: @Carlo in the video the gear is retracted 1 sec BEFORE the windshear aler, probably a concesion from the examiner. Please see the procedure card top-right at the 0:00 : do no change configuration (slats/flaps, gear) until out of windshear. I’m not gonna get too religious on this topic, so I am  not gonna say more than this:: retracting gear is against current operational practices

Comment: And I’d answer back that you do see evidence of wind shear even before the EICAS alert for it.  Look at the airspeed trend during the takeoff roll and departure.  The acceleration rate is not uniform - a telltale sign of wind shear in the area.  Once airborne, the situation allows for gear retraction so the crew opts for it.  As such the crew responds correctly- note they follow the wind shear checklist and don’t change the configuration once the EICAS alert is received.  The pilot handled the situation correctly and any examiner who would fail him for that is a fool, pure and simple.